# How can I set a select default value from a drop-down box in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following Angular code in my HTML file.
I have a drop-down box with two fixed choices: `A` and `B`.
The user must select either `A` or `B`. It cannot be left blank.
I would like the default selection to be `A`. How can I do it?

The following code starts off with an empty drop-down box. I don't want that. I want `A` to be pre-selected.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="myCtrl.param1">
    <option value="a" selected>A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
  </select><br/>
  <button ng-click="myCtrl.submit()">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: the code you've presented works exactly as you're requesting. Please provide more context for reproducible results. Double check `param1 == 'a'` too.

Comment: try to use  [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) .

Comment: If you don't use `selected`, empty selection will be there.

Comment: @Dineshaws `ng-selected="true"` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following illustrates the ways, by which one can do it:

**Option 1:** (by adding `ng-selected="true"`)

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="myCtrl.param1">
        <option value="a" ng-selected="true">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select><br />
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.submit()">submit</button>
</div>
```

*JS:*

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.submit = function () {
       /*..*/
    }

    $scope = myCtrl;
});
```

**Option 2:** (by setting the `variable` in the `controller`)

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="myCtrl.param1">
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select><br />
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.submit()">submit</button>
</div>
```

*JS:*

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.submit = function () {

    }
    myCtrl.param1 = "a";

    $scope = myCtrl;
});
```

If you do not want to pre-select any, but show a label then ->

**Option 3:** (by just showing a 'Select' label - no pre-select in this case)

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="myCtrl.param1">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select><br />
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.submit()">submit</button>
</div>
```

*JS:*

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.submit = function () {

    }
    $scope = myCtrl;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a variable in your controller as follows:

```
$scope.myCtrl.param1 = 'A';
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n9tL7cdr/2/

Comment: Why do you have `myCtrl` in there? In my example `myCtrl` is just an alias to `MyController`. But your controller's name is `testCtrl`. So then what is `myCtrl` for? I'm confused.

Comment: I just assigning a default value to your ng-model so it will display 'A'. You can change the name of the `testCtrl` to `myCtrl` so you cannot confused. Like this:https://jsfiddle.net/x8fghh3p/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ng-selected and based on key you can keep selected or not selected items for e.g

```html
<md-select ng-model="sms.from" ng-change="getSelectedValue(sms.from, 'from')">
  <md-option ng-repeat="(i,item) in fromNumber" ng-value="item" ng-selected="i == 0 ? true:false">{{ item }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Much easier solution: simply replace `selected` in my original question with `ng-selected="true"`. That works.